# jquery form creation and submit multiple parameters aren't arriving at controller

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes and I'm getting the values from them with:

```
var itemIds = [];

    $('input:checkbox.itemcheckbox:checked').each(function () {

      itemIds.push($(this).val());

    });
```

Then I'm taking these values and then I create a form:

```
    var form = $('<form/>', {
                        action: '@Url.Action("Process", "Items")',
                        method: 'GET',
                        css: { display: 'none' },
                        html: $('<input type="hidden" name="itemIds" value="' + itemIds + '"/>')
                    });
                    $('body').append(form);
                    form.submit();
```

On submitting the form the method on my controller is:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public FileStreamResult MoveToFinanceProcessing(IList<int> itemIds)
        {
            ...
        }
```

So the reason I've implemented things this way is because I'm trying to download a zip file and this is the only way I could get it to work.

The problem is that it only works for one checkbox checked. I can't get it to work for multiple item ids.

I know the problem is this line:

```
html: $('<input type="hidden" name="itemIds" value="' + itemIds + '"/>')
```

I can manually get multiple parameters to go to the method by going:

```
html: $('<input type="hidden" name="itemIds[0]" value="3"/><input type="hidden" name="itemIds[1]" value="4"/>')
```

The trouble is I can't get them into the html line from the itemIds variable like this.

Can someone please tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try this

```
html: $('<input type="hidden" name="itemIds[]" value="' + itemIds + '"/>')
```

so in the controller you will get an array.